# MongoDB query is slow on first view runs, but then dramatically speeds up afterwards

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-indexes

My MongoDB Atlas collection has 1 million documents and about 10 indexes.

I have a query that has arbitrary filter conditions.

I notice that sometimes whenever I create a new set of filter conditions it runs really slowly in the first 4 or 5 runs, taking about 16 seconds to return. But then afterwards, it speeds up dramatically and only take about 1 or 2 seconds to return.

What explains?

Comment: Sounds like the cache gnomes were napping.

Comment: I don't quite understand

Comment: That was intended as a joke.  Usually a query is slow the first run because everything has to be fetched from disk, after that it should be in the cache.  I really have no idea why it would be slow for 4 or 5 runs.

Comment: How long will the data stay in the cache?

Comment: Until the space is needed for something else.

Comment: I am opting to use MongoDB's serverless tier, where `resources scale seamless as you need it`. Could this be the reason the data isn't cached on the first run?